# mixed model formulation

Tags: mixed-model

I have 7 groups (groups), 20 fish in each group (fish.ID), 25 cells from each fish, and 4 measurements from each cell corresponding to head (head.len), ubody (ubody.len), lbody (lbody.len) and tail (tail.len).

So far I was fitting individual mixed models on each category of head, u body, lbody and tail like following:

head.len ~ groups + (1|fish.ID)
..
tail.len ~ groups + (1|fish.ID)

and computing p-values for each set to test a hypothesis whether the groups 2-7 differ from control group, group 1.

Now, I wish to analyze all data with one model but confused about the formulation. Would the following be appropriate:

```
cbind(head.len,ubody.len,lbody.len,tail.len) ~ groups + (1|fish.ID)
```

or this

```
len ~ groups + measurement_type + (1|fish.ID)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using 'melt' in R to merge the measurements of each fish and then ran the following model

len ~ groups + (1|part:fish.ID)

seems to be fine.